# how to make multiple columns unique together yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i try to create football table app. i have 3 tables - `teams(id, name)`, `matches(id, home_team_id, away_team_id, round_id)` and `rounds(id, round_num)`. `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` are foreign keys, reference to `teams` table. and `round_id` is f.k. references to `rounds` table. for example i have 4 teams - `juventus`, `milan`, `chelsea`, `arsenal`. so if i want to create match - first i create round. all i need here is just insert number of round(for example 4th round). then i go and add matches in this round -  choose home team(for example `juventus`) and then choose away team(for example `milan`) and then submit. the problem is, next time when i will create match, i shouldn't be able to create match that already been played. if `juventus` played home against `milan` user shouldn't be able to create this match again. so i need `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` to be unique together, and only together(not separately)! how should i do this? i tried to validate it like

```
[['home_team_id', 'away_team_id'],
         'unique', 'targetClass' => Match::className(),
       'targetAttribute' => ['home_team_id', 'away_team_id']],
```

but instead of prevent storing data and show error message,it override existing match

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an issue with your rule. If you remove the rule does the existing match still get overwritten? If so the issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it in your "Match" model's rules:

```
['home_team_id','unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['home_team_id', 'away_team_id']]
```

You must to make sure that:

1. Your attributes validation enabled `$model->save(true)`
2. Attribute exist in scenario array if you use it.

   ```
   public function scenarios(){
       return array_merge(parent::scenarios(), [
           ...,
           self::SPECIFIC_SCENARIO => ['home_team_id']
       ]);
   }
   ```